# How to normalize nested dictionary data coming from an excel file Using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, normalization

I have below excel data coming in and i am trying to normalize the data coming in few fields where the data is nested dictionary.

Example:

| custid | rules |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | {'tax':{'property_tax':1000,'schooltax':200}, 'hoa':195, 'pmi':'49'} |
| 101 | {'pmi':22} |
| 102 |  |

and I want to see some thing like this:

| custid | property_tax | schooltax | hoa | pmi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1000 | 200 | 195 | 49 |
| 101 |  |  |  | 22 |
| 102 |  |  |  |  |

I am using python 3.7 and pandas to normalize data.
But it's not working ? How do we normalize the above excel data ?

Comment: Please edit your code attempt to solve this into your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For a question like this, you should really post a minimal reproducible example: links/images are "extra", write your table in python. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1):

You should apply something like this :

```
df['property_tax'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['rules']['tax']['property_tax'], axis=1)
df['schooltax'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['rules']['tax']['schooltax'], axis=1)
df['hoa'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['rules']['hoa'], axis=1)
df['property_tax'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['rules']['pmi'], axis=1)
```

Edit : If some rows don't have values for some fields, you should use dict.get('x', '') instead of dict['x'], which would raise an error.